# Can I dynamically add a View to home screen widget?

Tags: android, android-appwidget

I am writing a home screen widget. Is it possible to add a View, e.g. ImageView, to a home screen widget through RemoteViews? I want to generate the views for the home screen widget dynamically.

Thanks.

```
            updateViews = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_news);

            updateViews.setTextViewText(R.id.widget_title, mTitle);

            updateViews.setImageViewBitmap(R.id.widget_picture, 
                        BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(image, 0, image.length));
```

My code is like above. But when I call `updateViews.addView(aView)`, my IDE didn't allow me to do that and give me an compile error.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you use `RemoteViews`, you are pushing the definition of your UI to the app widget. You want more `Views`? Just use an appropriate layout at that point when creating the `RemoteViews` instance.

Comment: I edited my post by adding some example code. I tried to call updateViews.addView(aView), but failed. Any thoughts?

Comment: As I wrote, "Just use an appropriate layout at that point when creating the RemoteViews instance". You will notice how your update code calls new RemoteViews() and supplies a layout. If you want a different layout for the app widget, switch to using a different layout file.

Comment: What if I want to dynamically generate the views in RemoteViews? For example, I read pictures from a database. The first time, I retrieve 3 pictures, so I create 3 ImageViews in the RemoteViews. The next time, I retrieve 5 pictures, then I create 5 ImageViews in the RemoteViews of the widget. Is it possible? Thanks.

Comment: I am with you, kknight. Dynamically would be the way to go.